# Match word that ends with "Id" using regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

How to put together a regex that will match words that end with "Id" doing a case sensitive match?

Comment: What about these words: `Id` (starts and ends with `Id`) and `O'HaraId` (do you want to match `O'HaraId` or `HaraId`) and `foo-barId` (do you want to match `foo-barId` or `barId`)? In short: please define what a "word" means (or what you want it to be).

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
\w*Id\b
```

`\w*` allows word characters in front of `Id` and the `\b` ensures that `Id` is at the end of the word (`\b` is word boundary assertion).

Comment: @epitka, note that `\w` also matches numbers and the underscore. In short the strings `___Id` and `12345Id` will also be matched.

Comment: I gave you an upvote, but epitka doesn't specify if just "Id" is allowable, so I'd be tempted to change the * for a +

Comment: I found it doesn't match string that end with ID.  you need to do \z at the end instead of \b

Answer (score 9):

Gumbo gets my vote, however, the OP doesn't specify whether just "Id" is an allowable word, which means I'd make a minor modification:

```
\w+Id\b
```

1 or more word characters followed by "Id" and a breaking space.  The [a-zA-Z] variants don't take into account non-English alphabetic characters.  I might also use \s instead of \b as a space rather than a breaking space.  It would depend if you need to wrap over multiple lines.

Answer (score 5):

How about `\A[a-z]*Id\z`? [This makes characters before `Id` optional. Use `\A[a-z]+Id\z` if there needs to be one or more characters preceding `Id`.]

Comment: Why `\z` worked with me, while the `\b` mentioned in all other answers not working?

Answer (score 5):

This may do the trick:

```
\b\p{L}*Id\b
```

Where `\p{L}` matches any (Unicode) letter and `\b` matches a word boundary.

Comment: does \p{L} work in C# regex?  I've never seen that one before and usually opt for \w

Comment: @BenAlabaster, yes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories And yes, perhaps `\w` is sufficient for the OP, but it matches more than letters (see my comment under Gumbo's post).

Answer (score 4):

I would use
    `\b[A-Za-z]*Id\b`
The \b matches the beginning and end of a word i.e. space, tab or newline, or the beginning or end of a string.

The [A-Za-z] will match any letter, and the * means that 0+ get matched. Finally there is the Id.

Note that this will match words that have capital letters in the middle such as 'teStId'.

I use http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for regex reference

Comment: The set `a-z` excludes `é` and other similar characters. Perhaps not an issue, but something epitka may want to know.

Comment: [A-Za-z] doesn't match non-English alphabetic characters, so should be avoided in favour of \w unless a guarantee can be made that only English letters will appear.

Answer (score 3):

```
Regex ids = new Regex(@"\w*Id\b", RegexOptions.None);
```

`\b` means "word break" and `\w` means any word character. So `\w*Id\b` means "{stuff}Id". By not including `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`, it will be case sensitive.