# How to replace words ending with -ing with a static string

Tags: c#, regex

In my block of code below, I am triyng to replace words ending with -ing with a static text "------". However, this doesn't seem to work and throws --- all over the place. What am I doing wrong?

```
string ingString = "I like programming, running, jobs and swimming.";
string ingWords = @"[^\\b\\w+(ing\\b)$]";
string staticLine = "------";
replaceString = Regex.Replace(ingString, ingWords, staticLine);
```

It should read "I like ------, ------, jobs and ------."

Thanks

Comment: Split string into words, find the words with your query, replace them with a straight line and then convert the string[] back to string.

Comment: I will see if I can figure out how to do that Afzaal, thank you.

Comment: How about something simple like `@"\b\w+ing\b"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
string ingString = "I like programming, running, jobs and swimming.";
string ingWords = @"\w+ing\b";
string staticLine = "------";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(ingString, ingWords, staticLine));
```

Output:

```
I like ------, ------, jobs and ------.
```

Now answering to your question:

> What am I doing wrong?

You regex:

```
[^\\b\\w+(ing\\b)$]
```

When you use brackets `[...]` it represents a set of characters, so the engine is trying to match all caracters inside your set, thats why its replacing a lot of chars with -----

Answer (score 2):

Your regex isn't right. Try this: `\w*ing\b`

Taken from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254749/regex-match-word-that-ends-with-id) but modified to suit your need.